# jQuery and preselected dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have some trouble with a HTML dropdown and jQuery.
One option is preselected

```
<select id="category">
 <option value="1" selected="selected">Value 1</option>
 <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

I try to get the selected value with this line

```
$("#category").val();
```

But I get always the preselected option "1".
Also variants like

```
$("select option:selected").val();
```

don't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where exactly you are trying to get the value? is it some event ?

Comment: For understanding. I don't want the text, I want value of a option. The code shown above returns only the preselected value "1" but never "2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
$("#category option:selected").text();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QLuk/1/)**

Because. `$('#category').val()` will output you the `value` attribute of selected option.In order to get the `text` of that selected option you need above.

Comment: Thank you! `$("#category option:selected").val();` seems to work in my case because I need the id.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#category").val()` gives you the selected option **value**.